# TCP data loss event

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, netstat

I have run the command `netstat -s` on a Linux server and got this line (under TcpExt) :

`15115 TCP data loss events`

does it mean that the data was completely lost complete or could it have been re-transmitted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [RFC793](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt) which is the RFC for TCP.  It explains that TCP "guarantees" delivery in the sense that the data will be confirmed to have been delivered, or the information will exist to show that the data was not delivered.

Within the operation of TCP the re-transmission of data can be commonplace - that's why TCP packets uses sequence and acknowledgement numbers.

So, to answer your questions, the data would never be "completely lost", and could certainly have been transmitted at some point during the TCP session.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I understand that tcp will not accidently miss data. What if the congestion window is full and the re-transmission don't get trough before the timeout? How can I know how many total loss connections I have had?